# How to proceed playing music after app have been killed?

Tags: android

After android appication have been killed, all the inner threads are stoped. How to proceed playing music using service and threads? Should I keep time of music in killing time and re-play from that exact time?

**EDIT**

I do use service and it plays in backgound. The only thing I want it to play when the app have been killed by user, in other words the music must be contolled only via notification buttons and not be related to application lifecycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your service a [Foreground Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). Then it will run even after the app is killed.